# Error: ph = item.get('pos_hint', ph) in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am getting this error when I run my program and have no idea what it means and I've been commenting out everything one at a time and it hasn't fixed it

```
ph = item.get('pos_hint', ph)
```

I have added the code I am running below, it is my original program that I have  re-formatted to allow for the change in size of a BoxLayout inside of a RecycleView, which was taken from a GitHub kivy example

```
MainInterface:

<MainInterface@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        #font_name: "Nunito-Black.ttf"
        text: "T            R           U             T            H"
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.12
        cols: 4
        Button:
            text: "Menu1"
        Button:
            text: "Menu2"
        Button:
            text: "Menu3"
        Button:
            text: "Menu4"
    PageLayout:
        border: "20dp"
        swipe_threshold: 0.2
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'PostGrid'
            scroll_y: 1
            id: rv
            data: app.posts
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id: box
                default_size: None, None
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                padding: ["10dp", "16dp"]
                spacing: "8dp"
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
                key_size: '_size'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                text: "peni"
            Button:
                text: "tag @ will J"
            Button:
                text: "Input"


<PostGrid@BoxLayout>:
    message_id: -1
    orientation: "horizontal"
    text: ''
    size_hint_y: None
    _size: 0, 0
    size: self._size
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        #size_hint: .1, 1
        Button:
            text: "UP"
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
        Button:
            text: "DOWN"
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
        Label:
            text: "test"
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
    Label:
        text: root.text
        color: 0,0,0,1
        #text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: None, 1
        size: self.texture_size
        #font_name: "Nunito-Bold.ttf"
        font_size: "12dp"
        smultiline: True
        #size: 1, root.min_height
        
        on_texture_size:
            app.update_message_size(
            root.message_id,
            self.texture_size,
            root.width)

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                size: self.texture_size
                radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]
                pos: self.pos
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:0,0.9,0.9,1
            Line:
                width:0.8
                rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, 5)
```

```
rom kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.metrics import dp

class TruthApp(App):
    posts = ListProperty({'message_id':0, 'text':"test", 'text_size': [None, None], 'side': "left"})

    def update_message_size(self, message_id, texture_size, max_width):
        # when the label is updated, we want to make sure the displayed size is
        # proper
        if max_width == 0:
            return

        one_line = dp(20)  # a bit of  hack, YMMV

        # if the texture is too big, limit its size
        if texture_size[0] >= max_width * 2 / 3:
            self.messages[message_id] = {
                **self.messages[message_id],
                'text_size': (max_width * 2 / 3, None),
            }

        # if it was limited, but is now too small to be limited, raise the limit
        elif texture_size[0] < max_width * 2 / 3 and \
                texture_size[1] > one_line:
            self.messages[message_id] = {
                **self.messages[message_id],
                'text_size': (max_width * 2 / 3, None),
                '_size': texture_size,
            }

        # just set the size
        else:
            self.messages[message_id] = {
                **self.messages[message_id],
                '_size': texture_size,
            }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TruthApp().run()
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: The attr. `posts` should be a list object if you are using `ListProperty`.Also looks like there's no reference for `self.messages` in your post. Please update it.

Comment: @ApuCoder OMG I cannot believe I didn't change the variable names from the example in the function, thank you